# Find the Infimum and supremum of M set

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

$$M = \bigcap_{n\in N}{I_n},$$
$$I_n = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{3^n - 2} \left(\frac{k}{3^n},\frac{k+1}{3^n}\right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

First prove that if $M=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}I_n$, then
$$
\sup M=\inf_n\sup I_n\\
\inf M=\sup_n\inf I_n
$$